# Assumptions for finding the area of a koch snowflake

Tags: sequences-and-series, fractals

I am currently in the process of finding the 1st, 2nd and 3rd iterations of the Koch snowflake, assuming the side length of the first iteration (the equilateral triangle) is 1.

Would there be any assumptions, besides the side length being 1, associated with finding these areas?

Comment: there is nothing much. At some step, you have a number $N$ of equal segments, all length $L.$ An equilateral triangle wide side length $L$ has area $A,$ which I expect is $L^2 \sqrt 3 / 2.$ Anyway, for each edge, you add a little triangle, so that now there are $4N$ edges; each new little triangle is of edge length $L/3,$ so its area is $A/9.$ There were $N$ of these added, so the area was increased by $NA/9.$

Comment: That area figure should have been $A = L^2 \sqrt 3 / 4,$ being half base times height.